# how to work with strings in Kotlin and string manipulation?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main (args: Array<String>) {
    val Myself = "Programmer"
    var Alphi = Myself[5]
    println(Alphi)
}
```

The above code works and outputs a.

- How can I use the same logic to output "grammer" in Alphi variable?

Comment: `var Alphi = Myself.substring(3)`, see the [API documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring.html).

Comment: var Alphi = Myself.substring(3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same you would do in Java:

```
val myself = "Programmer"
val alphi = myself.substring(3)
```

Comment: How can I change state of radio buttons in kotlin? Is it something like R.id.radioButton1.setChecked(false)??

Comment: Exactly like how you do it in Java.

Comment: I tried few but I would get the unresolved reference issue.